# ghost legend appearing when changing legend title in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have been trying for hours to adjust the title of my legend in a `ggplot2` line plot, but when I do I get a 'ghost legend' appearing below the real one.  I'm using the following code to adjust parts of my legend (coluor, line type and symbol in order):

```
scale_color_manual(values = c("#FF6600", "green4", "#0099FF")) +                 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "solid")) +  
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 16, 16)) +
```

This comes up with a lovely legend matching my graph.  However, when I try to add a title with this code:

```
labs(linetype='title')+
```

I get another legend appear below (so both are on the plot at the same time), with the correct title but none of the previous formatting.  Obviously I'm coding a separate legend, but I can't fix it!

Also, the real title I want to give my legend requires a subscript '2' for CO2, and I've used the following to account for that in other titles:

```
expression(CO[2]~concentration~(ppm))
```

Thought I'd mention that just in case it changes anything.

Aaaaand while I'm at it, I also want to change the legend orientation to being horizontal rather than a vertical list, and shift it to a corner of the plot space (tried `legend.position = c(0.9, 0.8)` which has worked before but not in this case).

My problem is that as I try each new thing, the errors compound and I can't move forward.

I realise this post is far from elegant, but any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sorry I have not provided any example code, I'm an R newbie and totally swimming.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data & code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please make a reproducible example - but your first problem is probably because if you want legends to be merged, they all need to have the same name, ie labs(linetype = "title", colour = "title", ...)

Comment: Welcome to SO, if there ever was a case where it was important to **show us** what you're referring to instead of **telling us**, it's this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be too new to create a reproducible example, so here's a try and an answer:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
df1 <- subset(diamonds, cut %in% (levels(diamonds$cut)[1:3]))[sample(100),]
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=carat, y=price, colour=cut, shape=cut, linetype=cut, group=cut))
p <- p + geom_line() 
p + scale_color_manual(values = c("#FF6600", "green4", "#0099FF")) +                 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "solid")) +  
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 16, 16)) +
  labs(linetype='title')
```

[image]

Is this the "ghost legend"?

Here's a workaround. The title should also be placed for the other aesthetics:

```
p + scale_color_manual(values = c("#FF6600", "green4", "#0099FF")) +                 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "solid")) +  
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 16, 16)) +
  labs(linetype=expression(CO[2]~concentration~(ppm)),
       colour=expression(CO[2]~concentration~(ppm)),
       shape=expression(CO[2]~concentration~(ppm)))
```

[image]

The extra legend is gone. This happened because of the differing names. We repeated the name for all of the aesthetics.

A shorter option is to add `guide="none"` to the other scales:

```
p + scale_color_manual(name=expression(CO[2]~concentration~(ppm)),
                       values = c("#FF6600", "green4", "#0099FF")) +                 
  scale_linetype_manual(guide="none",values=c("solid", "solid", "solid")) +  
  scale_shape_manual(guide="none",values = c(16, 16, 16))
```

Comment: Oh my goodness @Pierre Lafortune you interpreted my poor explanation perfectly and have solved my problem, thank-you so very much, I really appreciate your patience!  Everyone else, thanks for providing the opportunity for me to add more to my question, but I'm afraid Pierre was right and I just didn't know how to provide an example.  I've taken note of what Pierre did, and will try to do so in the future.  What a wonderful end to my week :-D